# Index of Coincidence (python)

Tags: python, cryptography

Hia guys, I'm helping out a friend with some code and so am trying to wrap my head around "Index of Coincidence" as seen here: http://jdege.us/crypto-python/ar01s08.html#id2963591

Essentially: I have a string output coming out of a for loop, and I want to calculate its index of coincidence, eventually I'll have it only displaying outputs which have a value over a threshold, but that can wait for now!

Any tips or guidance here would be appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific. Which part don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence). The index of coincidence of a text is defined as

[image]

where `c=26`, `n_i` is the frequency of each letter, and `N` is the length of the text.

Comment: Ha - turns out my major problem was in forgetting to remind python to use floats when dividing! Thanks for your help though guys :)